# Error: Unclassifiable statement when calling a function in Fortran

Tags: fortran

Why am I getting  `Error: Unclassifiable statement`?

I use Fortran 95 and use compile Fortran online : http://rextester.com/l/fortran_online_compiler

```
program main
  implicit none
    real::p = 0
    p=3**5 * exp(-3)/call fact(5)

    print*,p

end program main


function fact(n)
    implicit none
    integer :: n
    integer :: i
    integer :: fact

    if (n < 0)then
       fact = 1

    else   
       do i = 2, n, 1
          fact = fact * i
       end do

    end if   
end function fact
```

error:

```
 p=3**5 * exp(-3)/call fact(5)
   1 Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You will get much more attention.

Comment: Note that the definition of `fact` is broken.  What value do you expect it to return for `fact(0)` ?  and for `fact(1)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call a function using the `call` statement, that is only for subroutines. You just use the function name

```
 p=3**5 * exp(-3.0)/fact(5)
```

The argument to `exp` must be `real` (like `-3.0`).

You either have to put the function into a module (better) or make it internal (between `contains` and `end program`), or at least declare its type

```
 integer :: fact
```

in the program that is calling it.

Comment: Error: Return type mismatch of function ‘fact’ at (1) (UNKNOWN/INTEGER(4))

Comment: When I do not use call I receive

Comment: That is a different problem. Declare all types, including type return type of the function, or even better, put the function into a module.

Comment: Also note that exp takes a real or complex argument, not an integer